# SQL insert select @@Identity

Tags: sql-server

How to use the @@IDENTITY when I use INSERT SELECT ?

```
DECLARE @ENTITYID AS BIGINT

INSERT INTO Quiz_QuizQuestion
SELECT @ENTITYID,
       @DIFICULTLEVELCODE,
       ENTITYID,
       @QuizEntityId,
       Title,
       [Description],
       [Description],
       Duration
FROM   Education_Question
WHERE  EntityID = 1 --THIS SELECT RETURN JUST 1 RECORD
SET @ENTITYID = @@IDENTITY

SELECT @ENTITYID // NULL
```

Comment: Does `Quiz_QuizQuestion` actually have any columns defined as `IDENTITY`? (NB: 99% of the time you need `SCOPE_IDENTITY` anyway but shouldn't explain why `@ENTITYID IS NULL` here)

Comment: Well that's why it is NULL then. It [returns the last-inserted identity value.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) for your session.

Comment: I would recommend to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY` - you might get wrong results with `@@IDENTITY` (see [this blog post here for details](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/))

Comment: sql message :(1 row(s) affected) 
@@IDENTITY = **NULL**;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not insert @@IDENTITY into the table in your scenario - you have to **CREATE** table with **IDENTITY** field like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Quiz_QuizQuestion
(
  EntityId int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  ...
)
GO

DECLARE @ENTITYID AS BIGINT

INSERT INTO Quiz_QuizQuestion
SELECT 
       @DIFICULTLEVELCODE,
       ENTITYID,
       @QuizEntityId,
       Title,
       [Description],
       [Description],
       Duration
FROM   Education_Question
WHERE  EntityID = 1 --THIS SELECT RETURN JUST 1 RECORD
SET @ENTITYID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

SELECT @ENTITYID // NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

This is copied verbatim from the MSDN page about `@@IDENTITY`:
"After an `INSERT`, `SELECT INTO`, or bulk copy statement completes, `@@IDENTITY` contains the last identity value generated by the statement. **If the statement did not affect any tables with identity columns**, `@@IDENTITY` returns `NULL`. If multiple rows are inserted, generating multiple identity values, @@IDENTITY returns the last identity value generated." ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933167%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)). I don't know if you need more information than that.

Comment: sql message :(1 row(s) affected)
@@IDENTITY = NULL;

Comment: @Coelho - You said on a comment that your table doesn't have an identity column, so `@@IDENTITY` will be `NULL` after your insert

Comment: Sorry, the table have a key, EntityID is a primary key.

Comment: @Coelho - A primary key and identity column are completely different things. A primary key can be an identity, but **doesn't** have to be one.

Answer (score 1):

`@@identity` only gives the last value inserted in an `IDENTITY field`.

You need to create a `IDENTITY field` instead :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
--Create Table
--CREATE TABLE TableName (Col_A INT IDENTITY (1,1), Col_B NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO TableName VALUES ('TEST01')
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).